# How to fix Windows 10 app icons in the Start Menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, start-menu

Some of my Windows apps in the Start Menu are showing up with another (legacy) application's icon--ACDSee's, to be specific.

The apps all launch fine, they just have incorrect icons. Also, their icons are only incorrect when *searching* the Start Menu. Simply opening it and scrolling to the app shows the correct icon.

Just to make matters more complicated, Spotify is fine, while several others are not, including: Skype, Microsoft Store, and HP Smart.

Could it somehow be related to file associations? Like somehow, Windows thinks that these apps are .png files?? (Notice the choice of incorrect icon.)

Windows version:

20H2 (OS Build 19042.1415)

Here is what I tried:

1. Restart (not a shutdown).
2. sfc /scannow (found corrupt file and fixed them, but Restart didn't fix the problem).
3. DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth (nothing found)
4. Uninstall and reinstall Skype, for instance.
5. Uninstall ACDSee 2.43 and Restart (the application whose icon shows erroneously).
6. Googled "windows fix app icons in start menu" but didn't find anything useful.
7. Rebuild the Windows Index.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered upgrading your 20H2 installation to 21H2? Although based on [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/app-icons-are-missing-when-i-search-apps/6f837f98-3013-4e98-adf8-750506a8bfc2) sounds like a big fat incompatibility problem with the application.

Comment: Try rebuilding the icon cache  (Windows Club is currently offline.  .....  Rebuild Icon Cache in Windows 11/10
Open File Explorer > Folder Options > Views to show Hidden System Files.
Next, go to C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local folder.
Delete the hidden IconCache. db file. Reboot.
This action would purge and rebuild the icon cache.

Comment: @Ramhound - I forgot to mention that I did upgrade to 21H1 (and restarted) but no dice. Which application has the big fat incompatibility? ACDSee? 21H2? I guess I should try 21H2.

Comment: @John - Not sure what "Windows Club is currently offline..." refers to but I did as you suggested and deleted the IconCache.db file (and restarted) but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Yes; ACDSee appears to cause this behavior if it’s installed

Comment: I quoted the needed steps to try from Windows Club but you say rebuilding icon cache did not work